# How to draw on screen using hand gestures in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitouch, custom-draw

I want to draw on screen by moving my fingers across the screen.

How can we achieve this in iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to implement the touch sensing methods from [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) chain. The methods you need to implement are

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Inside this methods you can use Core Graphics drawing methods to draw custom drawing. [This](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024) tutorial will walk you through the steps.